# R Code: List containing column numbers to increment

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I am having a list containing the column numbers:

```
list = list(c(1,4,5),c(2,4,2))
matrix = matrix(rep(0,10),ncol=5)

> list
[[1]]
[1] 1 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 2 4 2


> matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

What I would want to achieve is:

```
> matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0
```

But because my list is huge and my matrix is huge, I am not satisfied with looping through:

```
for (i in 1:length(list)) matrix[i,list[[i]]] = 1
```

Comment: Your solution proved to be slow or you just don't like the fact it uses a loop?

Comment: Also, is this any better? `library(data.table) ; setDT(melt(list))[, table(L1, factor(value, levels = min(value) : max(value)))]`

Comment: Another option is `i1 <- as.matrix(transform(stack(setNames(list, seq_along(list))), ind= as.numeric(ind))[2:1]); matrix[i1] <- 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try `sparseMatrix` from `library(Matrix)`

```
library(Matrix)
sM <- sparseMatrix(i= rep(seq_along(list), lengths(list)), 
                    j= unlist(list),
                    x= 1)
as.matrix(sM)
```

Not sure the column numbers that were repeated in the same `list` element is typo or not.  If it is not a typo, and still want the binary output

```
+(!!(as.matrix(sM)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    0    0    1    1
#[2,]    0    1    0    1    0
```